# R using tidyr, reshape2 to convert multiple column sets to rows

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape2, tidyr

I've looked at many other examples out there for using gather, melt, or reshape to convert a wide format table to long format, but typically the examples are very simple. I need to use gather/melt/reshape (or other) functions to take this data:

```
dt <- data.table(Id=1:4, TopicA_Percent=runif(4,0.0,1.0), TopicB_Percent=runif(4,0.0,1.0), TopicC_Percent=runif(4,0.0,1.0),
             TopicA_Attempted=rnorm(4), TopicB_Attempted=rnorm(4), TopicC_Attempted=rnorm(4),
             TopicA_TimeSpent=rnorm(4), TopicB_TimeSpent=rnorm(4), TopicC_TimeSpent=rnorm(4))

ID TopicA_Percent TopicB_Percent TopicC_Percent TopicA_Attempted TopicB_Attempted TopicC_Attempted TopicA_TimeSpent TopicB_TimeSpent TopicC_TimeSpent
1      0.6639903      0.4219777      0.4099906      -0.09964646       1.05460385       -1.3331776      -1.55929389      -0.83446808      -1.53410657
2      0.7517089      0.2375559      0.8479702       0.25357552      -0.50835127       -0.2126446       0.31249508      -1.33036583      -0.07090781
3      0.1593582      0.5654915      0.1409356      -0.14667119       0.53910258       -0.5661078      -0.02883193       0.60079330      -1.00326670
4      0.6815283      0.1458051      0.8079253      -0.00262729      -0.08975263        0.8448300       1.39846994      -0.03548673      -1.09306706
```

and turn it into this:

```
Id  Topic   Percent  Attempted  TimeSpent
1 TopicA 0.3871205  0.3460178  0.1834476
2 TopicA 0.6431426 -0.6779898 -1.3497432
3 TopicA 0.5538110 -1.4967361  0.2576378
4 TopicA 0.8621070 -1.4911159  1.7140344
1 TopicB 0.4513063  1.2083898  1.4198672
2 TopicB 0.2045888 -1.2631067 -0.4347670
3 TopicB 0.6605945  0.3486036 -0.6111504
4 TopicB 0.5353699 -0.4743263 -0.4719514
1 TopicC 0.7887296  0.3327606  2.2776418
2 TopicC 0.7280900  0.5818754 -0.3294534
3 TopicC 0.7140528 -1.1317054 -1.3284694
4 TopicC 0.1647406  0.5157608 -1.4876869
```

I would prefer the solution involve tidyr or reshape2, but of course I am happy to get help using any method and perhaps I can extrapolate from that how to do it using one of the aforementioned libraries. Thanks!

Comment: So if you prefer a tidyverse solution why are you using `data.table` to create your data set?

Comment: @DavidArenburg that was just a snippet to help generate the data set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `data.table` methods i.e. `melt` which takes multiple `measure` `patterns`

```
dM <- melt(dt, measure = patterns("Percent$", "Attempted$", "TimeSpent$"), 
    value.name = c("Percent", "Attempted", "TimeSpent"), variable.name = "Topic")[,
       Topic :=  unique(sub("_.*", "", names(dt)[-1]))[Topic]][]
```

---

Or as @DavidArenburg mentioned, a compact option would be

```
dcast(melt(dt, id = "Id"), Id + sub("_.*", "", variable) ~ sub(".*_", "", variable))
```

Comment: I get an error when I run that code: `Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:5: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING`

Comment: @user2768331  Sorry, I didn't get any error with your example

Comment: I did something stupid, disregard previous comment. All working now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use `tidyr` you would use

```
library(tidyr)

dt %>% gather(key, value, -Id) %>%
  separate(key, c("topic", "category")) %>%
  spread(category, value)
```